# Best Libraries and Plugins for .NET to Write to Word

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, winnovative

What are the best libraries/plugins for .NET to access Word (create Word files and such)?  I have used the Winnovative Excel one so I might check out their Word one, but what are some others?

Comment: For excel you should be Using EPPlus cause it's free...I don't know of any word ones though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've always been partial to [Aspose.Words](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.words-for-.net/default.aspx). They have a whole line of components for other document types: PDF, Excel, etc.

Comment: Iv'e also used Aspose Words allot. Main benefit is the multiple output formats. (pdf, odt, doc...)

Answer (score 5):

I have used the free [Open SDK 2.0 from Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb448854.aspx) in the past, primarily to manipulate Office 2010 documents on the server (where installing the Office components is not recommended).

Since the Office 2010 file formats (e.g., XLSX, PPTX, etc.) are simply zip files containing a bunch of XML files, they can easily be manipulated without having to install any Office component.